# What are the main differences between G1GC and SGen GC

Tags: java, mono, garbage-collection, g1gc

What are the main differences between Java7's G1 garbage collector and mono's SGen garbage collector? I know both of them are of generational GC, but how are they different in performance wise and architecture wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, lets review both GC collectors:

- Mono's GC can be found in :

  - [Working with SGen](http://mono-project.com/Working_With_SGen)
  - [Generational GC](http://www.mono-project.com/Generational_GC).
- G1GC is described e.g. in [How does the Garbage-First Garbage Collector work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2881827/772000).

The [Working with SGen](http://mono-project.com/Working_With_SGen) defines that SGen is a generation collector that implements two GC algorithms for its Major Heap : (i) copying collector and (ii) mark-and-sweep.

Thereofre, although both SGEn and G1 are generational, fundamental difference is that G1 generations are split into many blocks of the same size while SGen applies a more traditional approach - one generation is represented as one continuous space.

Further, SGen's copying collector is by nature compacting. On the other hand, the Mark-And-Sweep algorithm is similar to the Java's CMS collector. And thus you can ask yourself, what is the difference between CMS and G1. There is a lot of information out there about their differences.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I beg to differ one of your comment - SGen is similar to the Java's CMS collector. CMS is not of compacting type where SGen is like G1.

Comment: Thanks, I checked SGen description again and updated the answer. It looks like it implements two collectors : Copying collector and MArk-and-Sweep. The first is compacting, the second one is not.

Comment: SGen's Mark And Sweep Collector does have the ability to also do compaction, as described in the above mentioned _Generational GC_ document under _Evacuation_.